# PHP pass multiple parameters on success in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing this ajax call

```
<script>
    function reserveSeat(showID) {  
        $.ajax({        
        url: 'reserve_seat.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "showID": showID}        
        }).done(function(data) {                    
            var booked_seats = JSON.parse( data1, data2, data3 ); //get multiple values 
            console.log(booked_seats);                     
        });
    };
    </script>
```

and in my reserve_seat.php I want to pass multiple echo

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `seats` WHERE show_id='" . $_POST['showID'] ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        $booked_seats = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push ($booked_seats, array($row['id'], $row['row_no'], $row['col_no']));   
    }
    echo json_encode($booked_seats, var2, var3); //echo multiple variable        
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

What I want is commented in the above code. How can I do this?

Comment: Where you getting the response data1, data2, data3 ? Only the `data`(single response message) as json return from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your echo line to :

```
echo json_encode(array("booked_seats" => $booked_seats, "var2" => $var2, "var3" => $var3);
```

And in your ajax

```
function(data) {                    
        var arr = JSON.parse( data );
        var booked_seats = arr["booked_seats"];
        console.log(booked_seats);                     
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just print the encoded JSON output?

Not to mention `json_encode()` requires an array as said by other posters

[json_encode() PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

use array in side

```
json_encode(array($booked_seats, var2, var3)).
```